# Watch unlock support now gone? (12.6.3 Monterey)

Tags: macos, icloud, apple-id, apple-watch

I've been using Watch unlock quite happily, including for sudo. However, it stopped working recently.

- Today, I noticed the Security & Privacy pane setting "Allow this mac to be unlocked with Apple Watch" unexpectedly unchecked.
- I tried to check it again, and was met with an error, [Apple ID not signed in]. All the other Apple ID linked services were still available and active, including for example active syncing of Notes.
- In the iCloud pane of System Preferences, I logged out and logged back in, but now the unlock with Watch checkbox no longer appears at all.

Can I re-enable watch unlock, or has Apple regressed this feature on Monterey?

(In re-authorizing & re-syncing iCloud, I'm a little disappointed to be asked for my phone lock pin on my Mac, instead of authorizing it from my phone. Bad training for users. Oh well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sign in with Watch has reappeared. It seems to have been an issue with iCloud partial sign-out or partial sign-in. Component services of iCloud seem to authorize separately, take time to sync, and finish syncing at different times. I got unlucky, (impatiently) observing the intermediate state.